# Converting name into numbers, then generate output

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++

Okay, I am taking a C++ class and am attempting to build a console program which the user input his/her name, and the program then outputs a new name based on every letter of the users name.

I am attempting to do this with a string, but have yet to find out how to properly convert the string into and int for each letter.

The only thing i have in this program is the replacement string for each char, but google and stackoverflow have shown nothing that i can apply to my current situation.
Here is my string:

```
string ninjaName[28] = {"ka", "zu", "mi", "te", "ku", "lu","ji", 
    "ri", "ki", "zu", "me", "ta", "rin", "to", "mo", "no","no", 
    "ke", "shi", "ari", "chi", "do", "ru", "mei", "na", "fu", "zi"};
```

The string represents the 28 letters in the alphabet and is based off of the "ninja name" picture.

I appreciate the help in advance!

Comment: 28 letters in the alphabet? What are the 2 extras?

Comment: @talnicolas, I'm going to say kana.

Comment: @talnicolas The names don't look like those of the Latin alphabet.  (For that matter, Latin only used 21 characters, where as modern Swedish has 29.  Even in the Latin alphabet, the number of characters varies.)

Comment: So what is this string to int conversion supposed to do?

Comment: I counted only 27 literals.

Comment: If you are attempting to translate each `char` in a string to the elements of `ninjaName` then use `std::map<char, std::string>`, where the key `char` is lowercase `char` of the name provided by the user.

Comment: @chris Or more generally, what is he actually trying to do?  It sounds somewhat like he's looking for a random permutation of the letters in the name, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: @jrok, That should be a compilation error as well.

Comment: I'm guessing OP is trying to convert A..Z to numbers to get an index for this array.

Comment: @chris But it is not.

Comment: @jrok If that's the case, @hmjd's answer is the cleanest way.  Or given the small size of the table, and the fact that it's constant, linear search (or binary search, if the table is initialized sorted) in a table of `struct { char key; char const* value }`.

Comment: @jrok, That's odd. I must be thinking of a different language or something. I guess the sensical part of it goes down the drain with constructs like `= {0}`. I completely forgot the last would just be an empty string.

Comment: @JamesKanze I'll take your word for it because I don't see any answers yet :)

Comment: http://liveworkspace.org/code/4rfgFn$1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I could understand, you're trying to use the ASCII code from each character of the user's input and replace it with another string.

There are two ways I would personally do it:

1. I would maintain the array that you have there. For each character in the user's input, I would test if it would be either a uppercase/lowercase character, if so, I would index the ninjaName array relatively to ASCII table.

Example:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string ninjaName[28] = {"ka", "zu", "mi", "te", "ku", "lu","ji", 
    "ri", "ki", "zu", "me", "ta", "rin", "to", "mo", "no","no", 
    "ke", "shi", "ari", "chi", "do", "ru", "mei", "na", "fu", "zi"};

int main(void)
{
    std::string input, newName;
    std::getline(std::cin,input);
    newName = "";
    char c; 

    for(unsigned int i=0; i < input.length(); ++i)
    {
        c = input[i];
        if (!isalpha(c))
            newName += c;
        else
            newName += ninjaName[tolower(c) - 'a'];     
    }

    std::cout << "Generated name: " << newName << std::endl; 
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Google ASCII table.

Another solution would consist of using a std::map, but both performance and simplicity wise, the solution above would be better.

Comment: On the other hand, your proposed solution supposes ASCII.  It's highly probably, but there are still machines out there that use other encodings.

Comment: My bad on the miscalculation, i simply spit this out so i would have a code of reference to add with my question. there are listed 27 "ninja" characters, two of them being "no". i kept getting a error when i had 26 in there and just did not feel like taking the time to correct it for this question. I will make sure to appease the trolls in the future. :D

Thank you for the help Ruben Cordeiro.

Comment: I will have to research most of this to understand what it does though! It does output a correct name after deskchecking.

Comment: Feel free to ask me anything about the solution, though it's  always better for you to figure it out. Remember: knowing C/C++ (specially the latter) revolves around knowing how to use the standard libraries.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include<iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string ninjaName[28] = {"ka", "zu", "mi", "te", "ku", "lu","ji", 
"ri", "ki", "zu", "me", "ta", "rin", "to", "mo", "no","no", 
"ke", "shi", "ari", "chi", "do", "ru", "mei", "na", "fu", "zi"};

int main()
{
    string name,outstr;
    int cindex=0;

    cout << "Enter Your Name:\t";
    cin >> name;
    size_t sz = name.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    {
        if(!isalpha(name[i]))
        {
            outstr+=name[i];
            continue;
        }
        cindex = tolower(name[i])-'a';
        outstr.append(ninjaName[cindex]);
    }
    cout << "\nyour new Ninja Name is:\t" <<outstr << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

<strike>Thats mostly in C, not C++, but</strike> it does what I think you're looking for.
a string is an array of chars, a char is just a number.

*Edit*
updated the code to c++, in turn fixing the problems as pointed out by James Kanze

Comment: It's also likely to crash (e.g. if the user enters a name of more than 64 characters).  (And it's really bad practice to call `strlen` each time in the loop.)

Comment: @JamesKanze You're quite right on both counts, I knocked this out off the top of my head, haven't tested it, Thanks. I shall edit it to fix those 2 points.